# Cannot checkout full SVN repository - operation timed out

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, apache, subversion

I am trying to checkout the SVN repository. However, I am still getting the connection timeout after some files are downloaded.

The error says:

> Cannot checkout from svn: svn: E000060: Operation timed out.

I am using the following command to checkout:

```
svn --username my_user co https://some_repo_url/project_name project_name
```

I increased the http_timeout value in the svn settings located in ~/.subversion/servers.

I am using the SVN version:

> svn, version 1.13.0
>   (r1867053)    compiled Feb  7 2020, 18:30:09 on
>   x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0